# Convert a java Hashmap<Mat, bool> to a c++ std::map<Mat, bool> with android ndk

Tags: c++, android-ndk

How to convert a java `Hashmap<Mat, bool>` to a c++ `std::map<Mat, bool>` with android ndk ?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no built-in way. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: mmh, how? I have no idea...

Comment: Pass each key/value pair separately...

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't write it : I want to pass the pointer of the map just one time and then fill the map on the java side, then calculate on the c++ side, and get the calculated result back on the map on the java side... Can I do it maybe with an array of structure? (the c++ is a thread)

Comment: You can do whatever you want on the C++ side, and you can do whatever you want on the Java side, but passing the map between those will be a huge pain no matter what you do.

Comment: @Adrien: You cannot easily make a native thread update data in a Java thread. If I were you, I'd forget about it. Move all multi-threading to Java (using the `AsyncTask` Android framework class) and let C++ only do whatever high-performance calculations are needed. `HashMap` has nothing to with `std::map`, other than meeting similar requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pass each key/value pair separately

by @immibis was the solution